# What would you call "shower box" in Portuguese?

Tags: vocabulário

What would you call "shower box" in Portuguese?

[image]

A friend told me that they just use "box". That seems colloquial to me. Is there a formal expression for that?

Comment: In English, that picture shows a shower enclosure (the technical word for it, like when you go buy one) or just a shower (in everyday speech). We don't say shower box in English. We say: shower stall. And in Portuguese, a shower is a chuveiro.

Comment: In Portuguese, the word box is used for a shower stall. (Brazilian Portuguese).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, as mentioned by @Lambie, your link shows the picture of a **"shower stall"** or **"shower cubicle"** which translates as **"box"** in Portuguese.  We don't say "o box do chuveiro", it's simply **"o box"**.

- Na idade dela é mais seguro ter um tapete anti-derrapante **dentro do box**.
- Achei **o box** do banho/banheiro muito pequeno.

Comment: Não se diz box do chuveiro, mas se diz box do banheiro. "Olha, o box quebrou!" essa frase não seria menos clara do que "Olha, o box do banheiro quebrou!". A menos que o contexto sugira que se trata do box do banheiro como na primeira frase por causa do "tapete antiderrapante". Box é uma palavra emprestada que perdeu seu significado original, e alguém ainda pode confundir com boxe.

Comment: @AndréLyra   Não entendi bem teu comentário.  *"essa frase não seria menos clara..."*  Tu queres dizer que *seria mais clara* ?  Quanto ao box do banheiro, foi exatamente o que escrevi, sem nenhum contexto, é preciso especificar que trata-se do box do banheiro ou, até mesmo, o box do banheiro da suite.   Quanto a "o box do banheiro quebrou", acho que ficava melhor: o blindex do box quebrou, o vidro do box quebrou, a porta do box quebrou, o piso do box quebrou.  O *box do banheiro* quebrou soa estranho porque o box é o cubículo.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Melhor especificar. Ainda que existam Cama Box e Box de banheira. E se use box comercialmente para outros tipos de caixas como armários e baús.

Comment: @AndréLyra  Então tu queres dizer que a frase "Olha, o box quebrou" é mais clara do que "Olha, o box do banheiro quebrou."   É isso o que tu afirmas com...  *essa frase não seria menos clara do que...*  Confesso que parece contradizer o resto do parágrafo.

Comment: "Olha, o box quebrou!" esta frase não seria menos clara do que "Olha, o box do banheiro quebrou!"? Eu pensei com interrogação mas não pontuei corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Em portugues de portugal (pt-pt) I never even heard the word "**box**" to refer to the place where you take a bath or its structure.

Normally we call that simply chuveiro (if you can only take a bath while standing, which would be a shower stall).

We can also use banheira (equivalent to banheiro in pt-br, which would be a bathub).

We would say

> A porta do chuveiro está estragada.

In free translation: The door of the shower stall is broken.

Comment: Bruno "banheiro" no pt-BR é casa de banho ou WC. De resto de acordo.

Comment: Em casa dos meus pais sempre chamámos *[polibã](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/polib%C3%A3)*, mantive o uso do termo até hoje. Pensei que fosse standard. No site do Aki chamam de *cabine de duche*. No IKEA não vendem. Não me ocorrem agora outras lojas onde procurar que termo usam, mas quer-me parecer que não há um termo standard. Pessoalmente acho que nunca ouvi referir "a caixa" como simplesmente *chuveiro*.

Comment: @GitGud Sim, poliba também conheco